# Custom Module tags seem to be parsed twice if stylesheet link is passed back to template

Tags: parse-order, custom

I’ve built a module that creates a new file from tagdata between a tag pair, before creating the new file if a similar file already exists it moves it to an archive folder, it then writes the path to the new file back to the template, this is the part that’s causing problems; the new file gets created, and the existing file gets archived, however if I try to return or echo the new file path back to the template it causes the new file to also get copied to the archive folder.

Template tags:

```
{exp:custom_mod:test}
    Some data.....
{/exp:custom_mod:test}
```

Module code:

```
public function test()
{
    $page_data = ee()->settings_model->get_settings();

    //fetch all files from folder
    $directory = $page_data['folder_path'];
    $pattern = "custom.*txt";
    $files = ee()->file_model->folder_iterator($directory, $pattern);

    //move existing to achive folder
    ee()->file_model->move_to_archive($files);

    //create new file and get link to it
    $name = ee()->file_model->create_new_file();

    $link_text = "<link href=\"$name\" rel=\"stylesheet\">;

    // this works as expected
    return;

    //this causes more than one new file to be created
    return $link_text;
}
```

So it seems that writing the new file path back to the template perhaps causes the module tag to be parsed again (I can't think of another explanation).

Is this what’s happening? How do I stop it?

Comment: Don't have time to recreate a test setup right now, but unclear whether you are saying that it is the addition of `$link_text` to the `return` line that causes the problem, or simply the inclusion of the `return` line with or without a return variable.  Wondering what happens if you return `$name` rather than `$link_text`.  Also - would be good form to include in your question the version EE you are working with.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, if I add a link to the return it causes problems, an empty return or return true, works as expected, but i need to send a link to the page

Comment: Just a thought - what happens if you send back the `$name` value and build the http tag within your template?

Comment: It works as expected then

Comment: also, if I just return the name of the new file and build the rest of the link in the template it still copies the new file to the archive folder!

Comment: @JCOGS Design I've updated the question as I realised this only causes an issue with stylesheets

Comment: Weird. I'll see if I can find time at weekend to simulate on a local system - if possible can you provide some more details of what kinds of files are in the folder that you are working on - if file type is an issue useful if I get the right ones.  Also what version of EE / client software / browser are you using?